# Import through multiple index.ts

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

We use a create-react-app with typescript. When running the jest tests I get an error when calling a function imported through multiple index.ts. It works in the browser though.

Is there any know issue when importing over several index.ts-files like below. . Btw. importing is fine, it only fails when calling the function.

```
-  function A
|
-> index.ts re-export A --
                         |
-  function B using A <---
|
-> index.ts re-export B -
                        |
   using function B <----
```

- no repo yet ro reproduce
- "typescript": "3.4.5" (but tested with 3.5 as well)
- "react-scripts": "3.0.1", ( but tested with 3.1.1)

** Update **
Ok, thx to @sykboyer I found what the problem was. I try to explain:

- I call a function in the 2nd index, resolving the first index.ts
- In the browser I always first included the 2nd index.ts which then included the first one.
- In some tests I did it the other way around leading to undefined imports in the function

Comment: may you add code with `export`/`import`? is there circular dependency?

Comment: I'll check whether I have a circular dependency. That's a good hint. But still I wonder why it then only happens when I call the function and not already on importing it.

I cannot share the original repo, but I hope to find some time latter this afternoon, or on Monday to reproduce it.

Comment: in your question you says you get an error while importing, in comment you say you get import while trying to call thing imported. so what's actual point? also it'd be better to see error message as well as sample with `export`/`import` and file structure

Comment: sry I was a bit in a hurry. I updated the question to be more precise. The error messages vary. I add them above as well.

Comment: I guess I found it. thx for your help. If you wish you can formulate an answer.

Comment: please make an answer - so it may help someone who reach here  by search(I only provided a guess so still unsure what was the root cause in this case)